# Navigate to named anchors scrolling up and down on click - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi this is my first question on SO.
I have elements in a nav div and in a different content div, on the same page, I have elements with ids. I want the content div to scroll the corresponding id element to the top of the content div, on click of the nav element. I've found code that will take me to the content element on click but then I have to go back to the top of the div to click to a different content element. I just want to be able to click any nav element at any time and the div will scroll to display the corresponding content at the top of the content div.

```
<div class="nav">
        <span class="list-testimonials-group-item" id="1_1">to img 1</span>
        <span class="list-testimonials-group-item" id="2_2">to img 2</span>
        <span class="list-testimonials-group-item" id="3_3">to img 3</span>
 </div>

<div class="content>
    <img id="1">
    <img id="2">
    <img id="3">
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are your A tags?

Answer (score 0):

What you need it's to put that nav div in position fixed on the css, so when you use the anchor, the nav content will follow the user's screen:

```
.nav {
  position: fixed;
}
```

TIP: Use nav html5 instead, helps on SEO features.

Answer (score 0):

I created an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/2atmtap6/1) here. In this example there a two links at top that scrolls to associated elements when clicked.

```
<a href="#test1"> go to 1</a>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. My solution requires a fixed nav  that targets anchors in an adjacent div, and scrolls that div up and down depending on where in the div the anchor is located.